# Graphics is getting cut off by Swing components

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel

I am attempting to make a program where the user can enter x and y values for 3 points and then those 3 points will be drawn. However, the text fields and buttons (I think) are causing the graphics to cut off.

Window Class

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Window {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Points frame = new Points();
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


        }
}
```

Points class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Points extends JFrame{
    private JTextField x1;
    private JTextField y1;
    private JTextField x2;
    private JTextField y2;
    private JTextField x3;
    private JTextField y3;
    private JButton button;
    private JLabel label;
    static int nx1=0, nx2=0, nx3=0, ny1=0,  ny2=0, ny3=0;


    public Points(){

        x1 = new JTextField("0", 2);
        y1 = new JTextField("0", 2);
        x2 = new JTextField("0", 2);
        y2 = new JTextField("0",2);
        x3 = new JTextField("0", 2);
        y3 = new JTextField("0", 2);
        button = new JButton("Submit");
        label = new JLabel();

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                String sx1=x1.getText();String sx2=x2.getText();String sx3 = x3.getText();
                String sy1 = y1.getText();String sy2 = y2.getText(); String sy3 = y3.getText();

                nx1 = Integer.parseInt(sx1);
                nx2 = Integer.parseInt(sx2);
                nx3 = Integer.parseInt(sx3);
                ny1 = Integer.parseInt(sy1);
                ny2 = Integer.parseInt(sy2);
                ny3 = Integer.parseInt(sy3);


            }
        });

        add(x1);
        add(y1);
        add(x2);
        add(y2);
        add(x3);
        add(y3);
        add(button);
        add(new Panel());

    }
}
```

Panel Class

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Panel extends JPanel{

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        System.out.println(Points.nx1);
        g.drawRect(Points.nx1, Points.ny1, 5,5);
        g.drawRect(Points.nx2, Points.ny2, 5,5);
        g.drawRect(Points.nx3, Points.ny3, 5,5);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use `paintComponent(Graphics g)` for swing components and set the layout of the panel inside the constructor itself. you are calling the `setLayout` method after all the components have been added.

Answer (score 2):

A FlowLayout respects the preferred size of all components added to the panel.

1. Your Panel class does not have a preferred size so it defaults to (10, 10) because the FlowLayout by default has a gap or 5 pixels before/after each component added to the panel. So you need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your Panel class to return the appropriate dimension that will contain all of your custom painting code.
2. Custom painting is done by overriding paintComponent() (not paint) as has already been mentioned.
3. You should never invoke repaint() in a painting method. This will cause an infinite loop.
4. Don't forget to add a super.paintComponent(..) statement at the top of the paintComponent() method to make sure the background gets repainted.